# Changing the queue for an already submitted PBS job

Tags: pbs

I have a job already submitted to a TORQUE queue. The system I submitted it on has several queues, and I want to change which queue I'm running it in. I found [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/112/81), which recommends the use of `qalter`, but `qalter`'s man page doesn't have instructions for changing the queue.

**EDIT**:
I tried `qalter -q <queuename> <jobid>` and I get an error message `qalter: illegally formed job identifier: <queuename>`

**How can I change which queue a job is submitted to using a PBS system?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old question,  but the correct command to move a queued job from one queue to another in torque is "qmove" and not qalter.

From [man page](http://qcd.phys.cmu.edu/QCDcluster/pbs/PBS_qmove.html):

Usage: `qmove destination job_identifier ...`

Description:

> To move a job is to remove the job from the queue in which
>   it resides and instantiate the job in another queue. The
>   qmove command issues a Move Job batch request to the batch
>   server that currently owns each job specified by
>   job_identifier. A job in the running state cannot be moved by the user.

Comment: qmove is the only command that would work!

Answer (score 7):

The command

`qalter -q <new queue name> <jobid>`

should work for already submitted jobs. For new jobs use the same syntax with qsub

`qsub -q <new queue name> <scriptname>`

Please note that if your job is already running, the qalter will not make it switch queues. Only if the running job gets interrupted and restarted, it will switch queue.

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: Are the angle brackets part of the syntax of the qalter command?

Comment: @Dan: No, they are not. if you want to move the job with jobid 1234 to the queue named DansQueue, you should enter the command `qalter -q DansQueue 1234`. Make sure that you are allowed by your sysadmin to submit in that queue

Answer (score 6):

In Torque only this works:

```
   qalter <jobid> -W queue=<new queue name>
```

Comment: This is the only command that worked for me. Thanks!